# How similar are permutation groups that are isomorphic as abstract groups?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

Let's say that two permutation groups $P_1$ and $P_2$ are isomorphic as abstract groups, but not necessarily permutation isomorphic. How similar will $P_1$ and $P_2$ be, and how much structure will the isomorphism preserve?

Here are some things we know:

- The identity permutation will map to the identity permutation.
- Group theoretic properties, such as order and inverses, will be preserved.
- The cardinality of the set underlying the isomorphism will *not* necessarily be preserved, even if we require that no element is a fixed point of every permutation.

I guess the flip-side of the question is how *different* can isomorphic permutation groups be?

EDIT: The reason I ask this question is I'm wondering how feasible it is to study group theory purely in terms of permutation groups. By [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem), every group is isomorphic to a permutation group, so it seems like it should be feasible.

Comment: What does "not necessarily permutation isomorphic" mean?

Comment: @lhf See [permutation isomorphic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Permutation_isomorphic_groups)

Comment: Somewhat extreme case (assuming transitivity): $S_n$ as permutation group on $\{1,\dots,n\}$, an as permutation group on itself ($n!$ elements).

Comment: @YCor Even then, a lot of structure is preserved, even if cardinality isn't. I'm pretty sure, for example, that the cycles in the second are just sets of corresponding cycles in the first of a fixed cardinality.

Comment: Cycles? for the simply transitive action on $n!$ elements, an element of order $k$ acts as $n!/k$ $k$-cycles. While on $n$ elements, it has its own structure; for example $(12)(345)$ of order 6, acts as what it is (1 2-cycle, 1 3-cycle, $n-5$ 1-cycles).

Comment: I think it's worth looking at where permutation representations come from. Look at a group acting on the cosets of a subgroup. And orbits. And also think hard about a permutation group like this: $\langle(1\,2\,3\,4)(5\,6),(5\,6\,7)\rangle$

Comment: @YCor Oh, nvm then.

Comment: @YCor My edit might help clarify the question.

Comment: Don't you know that group theory was introduced though permutation groups? There's a whole treaty by Jordan with this point of view (traité des substitutions, 1870). Abstract groups appeared later.

Comment: A possible answer relies on a reading of Cayley's theorem that goes back to what I understand is its original meaning. Take *any* permutation group $G$ on a set $\Omega$. So this could have many orbits, with various stabilizers, etc. Now Cayley's theorem tells you that the abstract group $G$ is also a permutation group on a set $\Delta$ on which it acts regularly, that is, it has just one orbit, and the stabilizers are trivial.

Comment: I think you should reverse the question: given some abstract finite group $G$, how different are its various faithful actions on finite sets? And in general they are pretty different.

Answer (score -2):

This is an example of "how different" isomorphic permutation groups can be. The following subgroups of $S_4$ are all cyclic of order $4$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&H_1:=\langle (1243)\rangle \\
&H_2:=\langle (1234)\rangle \\
&H_3:=\langle (1324)\rangle \\
\end{alignat}
but the "linearity" condition $\forall i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$:
$$\sigma(i)=i\sigma(1)\pmod 5$$
holds for every element of $H_1$, but for no nontrivial one of $H_2$ and $H_3$.